# Ubuntu 16.10 not detect sound card

Tags: sound, 16.10, soundcard

My sound card was working great and after a reboot it stopped working. Now, if I try `aplay -l`, it says "no sound card detected". I use the front headphone jack on my crosshair v formula motherboard. I also tried using the rear speakers but it doesn't seem to work either.

I have tried to delete alsa with `sudo apt-get --purge remove linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils pulseaudio` and then reinstall everything but it still doesn't work.

Anybody has a hint for me ?